# Errors when running program

Tags: haskell, syntax

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to create a program that searches a directory and prints a list of files in the directory and its sub directories. I am stuck with debugging my errors. I have no clue what is wrong and unfortunately, I am not finding the documentation and various tutorial aids online to be helpful.

This is the code that I have come up with. However, I have no idea if it works because I cannot get past debugging the errors.

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Directory
import System.FilePath
import System.Posix.Files

printDirectory :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
printDirectory = do
    let filesInCurDir = getCurrentDirectory >>= getDirectoryContents
    forM filesInCurDir $ \fry -> do
      isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fry </>
        if isDirectory
           then do printDirectory
           else putStrLn fry
      putStrLn "Directory search completed"
    return
```

Below are my error messages (sorry, it is a bit lengthy). I realize that some of my logic may be a little flawed, particularly with the recursive call in the if statement. Unfortunately, I can't get past the debugging to even begin to fix the logic. Please can someone help explain why I am getting the errors I am getting and how to fix them.

--Error Messages--

```
ass3.hs:13:9: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘FilePath -> IO [FilePath]’
                  with actual type ‘[b0]’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        forM filesInCurDir
          $ \ fry
              -> do isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fry
                                     </> if isDirectory then ... else putStrLn fry
                    putStrLn "Directory search completed"
      In the expression:
        do let filesInCurDir = getCurrentDirectory >>= getDirectoryContents
           forM filesInCurDir $ \ fry -> do ...
           return
      In an equation for ‘printDirectory’:
          printDirectory
            = do let filesInCurDir = ...
                 forM filesInCurDir $ \ fry -> ...
                 return
   |
13 |         forM filesInCurDir $ \fry -> do
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...

ass3.hs:14:31: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO Bool’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: FilePath
        Actual type: IO Bool
    • In the first argument of ‘(</>)’, namely ‘doesDirectoryExist fry’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fry
                         </> if isDirectory then do printDirectory else putStrLn fry
      In the expression:
        do isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fry
                            </> if isDirectory then do printDirectory else putStrLn fry
           putStrLn "Directory search completed"
   |
14 |                 isDirectory <-doesDirectoryExist fry</>
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ass3.hs:14:50: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: FilePath
        Actual type: [FilePath]
    • In the first argument of ‘doesDirectoryExist’, namely ‘fry’
      In the first argument of ‘(</>)’, namely ‘doesDirectoryExist fry’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fry
                         </> if isDirectory then do printDirectory else putStrLn fry
   |
14 |                 isDirectory <-doesDirectoryExist fry</>
   |                                                  ^^^

ass3.hs:15:28: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’
                  with actual type ‘FileStatus -> Bool’
    • Probable cause: ‘isDirectory’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the expression: isDirectory
      In the second argument of ‘(</>)’, namely
        ‘if isDirectory then do printDirectory else putStrLn fry’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fry
                         </> if isDirectory then do printDirectory else putStrLn fry
   |
15 |                         if isDirectory
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^

ass3.hs:16:41: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘FilePath -> IO [FilePath]’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: FilePath
        Actual type: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
    • Probable cause: ‘printDirectory’ is applied to too few arguments
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: printDirectory
      In the expression: do printDirectory
      In the second argument of ‘(</>)’, namely
        ‘if isDirectory then do printDirectory else putStrLn fry’
   |
16 |                                 then do printDirectory
   |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ass3.hs:17:30: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO ()’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: FilePath
        Actual type: IO ()
    • In the expression: putStrLn fry
      In the second argument of ‘(</>)’, namely
        ‘if isDirectory then do printDirectory else putStrLn fry’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fry
                         </> if isDirectory then do printDirectory else putStrLn fry
   |
17 |                         else putStrLn fry
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^

ass3.hs:17:39: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: [FilePath]
    • In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely ‘fry’
      In the expression: putStrLn fry
      In the second argument of ‘(</>)’, namely
        ‘if isDirectory then do printDirectory else putStrLn fry’
   |
17 |                         else putStrLn fry
   |                                       ^^^

ass3.hs:18:17: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
      Expected type: [()]
        Actual type: IO ()
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn "Directory search completed"
      In the expression:
        do isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fry
                            </> if isDirectory then do printDirectory else putStrLn fry
           putStrLn "Directory search completed"
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘\ fry
           -> do isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fry
                                  </> if isDirectory then ... else putStrLn fry
                 putStrLn "Directory search completed"’
   |
18 |                 putStrLn "Directory search completed"
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

ass3.hs:19:9: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[b0]’
                  with actual type ‘a0 -> m0 a0’
    • Probable cause: ‘return’ is applied to too few arguments
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: return
      In the expression:
        do let filesInCurDir = getCurrentDirectory >>= getDirectoryContents
           forM filesInCurDir $ \ fry -> do ...
           return
      In an equation for ‘printDirectory’:
          printDirectory
            = do let filesInCurDir = ...
                 forM filesInCurDir $ \ fry -> ...
                 return
   |
19 |         return  
   |         ^^^^^^
```

Comment: `printDirectory :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]` but you’re taking no parameter and using `getCurrentDirectory` instead.

Comment: You forgot to use a parameter here.

Comment: Please format error messages as well. Thanks.

Comment: @RookyCoder Having a legible post *does* help you with your problem, by making it more likely that someone will answer your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, GHC error message can be pretty baffling, but I'll try to talk you through this set.  The first error message is actually one of the hardest to understand, so let's skip to the second.  This one says that:

> - when GHC was looking at the first argument to `(</>)`, namely the expression `doesDirectoryExist fry`
> - it **EXPECTED** to find a `FilePath` (because the `(</>)` operator's first argument is obviously supposed to be a `FilePath`)
> - but instead it **ACTUALLY** found an `IO Bool`

If you check the type of `doesDirectoryExist`, you can see that -- indeed -- it takes a `FilePath` and returns an `IO Bool`, so GHC is right, you cannot supply a `doesDirectoryExist fry` (which has type `IO Bool`) as some sort of `FilePath`.

I'm not quite sure what paths you were trying to combine with `(</>)`, but if we get rid of that operator entirely and reformat, the following looks more like what you intended:

```
printDirectory :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
printDirectory = do
    let filesInCurDir = getCurrentDirectory >>= getDirectoryContents
    forM filesInCurDir $ \fry -> do
      isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fry
      if isDirectory
         then do printDirectory
         else putStrLn fry
      putStrLn "Directory search completed"
    return
```

If you recompile with this version, the first error message has changed a bit, but it's still confusing.  However, the second error message has disappeared, so things are improving!!  The third error message (now actually the second error message) is the same as before.  It says that:

> - when GHC was looking at the expression `fry` (the first argument to `doesDirectoryExist`)
> - it **expected** a `FilePath`
> - but it **actually** found a `[FilePath]`

This is strange!  We expected a `FilePath`, too, not a whole list of `FilePath`s.  That's what the `forM` was supposed to do.  What's happened here is that some other error, which isn't obvious, has caused GHC to mis-type `fry` as `[FilePath]` instead of `FilePath`.  To work around this, let's fake it by overriding `fry`s value with a `let` statement:

```
printDirectory :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
printDirectory = do
    let filesInCurDir = getCurrentDirectory >>= getDirectoryContents
    forM filesInCurDir $ \fry -> do
      let fry = "__FAKEFILEPATH__" -- DEBUGGING       -- << CHANGE HERE
      isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fry
      if isDirectory
         then do printDirectory
         else putStrLn fry
      putStrLn "Directory search completed"
    return
```

If we recompile, we're down to three errors.  The first error, stubborn as ever, is still confusing.  The second error message is a variant of the fifth message in the original list:

> ```
> Directory.hs:13:18: error:
>       • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO ()’
>                     with actual type ‘FilePath -> IO [FilePath]’
>       • Probable cause: ‘printDirectory’ is applied to too few arguments
>         In a stmt of a 'do' block: printDirectory
>         In the expression: do printDirectory
> ```

Here, GHC feels that the expression `do printDirectory` should have had type `IO ()` but instead had type `FilePath -> IO [FilePath]`, and it helpfully suggests that you've called `printDirectory` with too few arguments (which is true, as `printDirectory` needs a file path).  Let's supply `fry` for now, even though we might need to do something different later to get the recursion right.

```
printDirectory :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
printDirectory = do
    let filesInCurDir = getCurrentDirectory >>= getDirectoryContents
    forM filesInCurDir $ \fry -> do
      let fry = "__FAKEFILEPATH__" -- DEBUGGING
      isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fry
      if isDirectory
         then do printDirectory fry -- FIXME      -- << CHANGE HERE
         else putStrLn fry
      putStrLn "Directory search completed"
    return
```

This doesn't really clear up the error, though.  Now, GHC tells us that:

> ```
> Directory.hs:14:15: error:
>       • Couldn't match type ‘()’ with ‘[FilePath]’
>         Expected type: IO [FilePath]
>           Actual type: IO ()
>       • In the expression: putStrLn fry
>         In a stmt of a 'do' block:
>           if isDirectory then do printDirectory fry else putStrLn fry
> ```

Basically, in Haskell, the `then` and `else` branches of an `if` statement have to have the same type, but you're trying to return a list of files on one branch (because `printDirectory` returns type `IO [FilePath]`) but *print* a filename (which has type `IO ()`) on the other branch.

I guess you have to decide here if you want to *print* files or *return* files.  You said in your question you wanted to *print* them, so I'm going to guess that your `printDirectory` signature is wrong.  If you're just printing, then that's an IO action that doesn't return anything (or at least not anything useful), so the signature ought to read:

```
printDirectory :: FilePath -> IO ()
```

If you recompile, you'll get two errors.  The first is the same as before, the second is the same as the last error on your original list:

> ```
> Directory.hs:15:5: error:
>       • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO b0’
>                     with actual type ‘a0 -> m0 a0’
>       • Probable cause: ‘return’ is applied to too few arguments
> ```

The last line of your program seems to have a weird actual type.  Thankfully, GHC explains that you probably forget to supply an argument to `return`.  In fact, it's not clear what you were trying to return here (and when you posted your code, you seemed to have left it out, so maybe you already decided to delete this `return`).  Anyway, if we drop it, we're left with only one error:

> ```
> Directory.hs:9:5: error:
>       • Couldn't match expected type ‘FilePath -> IO ()’
>                     with actual type ‘IO (IO ())’
>       • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
>           forM filesInCurDir ...
> ```

Here, GHC has decided that the `forM ...` statement in your do-block should have had type `FilePath -> IO ()`, but it actually had type `IO (IO b)`.

This is confusing, but both the actual and expected type are wrong!  The `forM` statement should have been an IO action to print a bunch of filepaths, so it ought to have had type `IO ()`.

Here's what's happened.  In Haskell, the type of a do-block is the type of its last statement, and GHC has somehow decided that the whole outer do-block should have type `FilePath -> IO ()` which is why it expects the last statement to have that type.  Why does it think the outer do-block should have type `FilePath -> IO ()` instead of `IO ()`?  Well, because you told it that `printDirectory` should have type `FilePath -> IO ()` and then bound the do-block directly to `printDirectory` without giving `printDirectory` an argument.  You need to write `printDirectory dir = do ...`, like so:

```
printDirectory :: FilePath -> IO ()
printDirectory dir = do                        -- << CHANGE HERE
    let filesInCurDir = getCurrentDirectory >>= getDirectoryContents
    forM filesInCurDir $ \fry -> do
      let fry = "__FAKEFILEPATH__" -- DEBUGGING
      isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fry
      if isDirectory
         then do printDirectory fry -- FIXME
         else putStrLn fry
      putStrLn "Directory search completed"
```

Now the error message reads:

> ```
> Directory.hs:9:5: error:
>       • Couldn't match type ‘IO ()’ with ‘()’
>         Expected type: IO ()
>           Actual type: IO (IO ())
>       • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
>           forM filesInCurDir ...
> ```

When you see an `IO xxx` versus `IO (IO xxx)` mismatch cropping up in your code, it's usually because you've written a do-block statement as:

```
let x = something
```

when it should have been:

```
x <- something
```

Here, if we check the type of `getCurrentDirectory >>= getDirectoryContents` in GHCi, we see it has the type:

```
> :t getCurrentDirectory >>= getDirectoryContents
getCurrentDirectory >>= getDirectoryContents :: IO [FilePath]
```

so it's an IO action to return a list of filepaths.  However, we've assigned it with `let` to `filesInCurDir`.  But we don't want `filesInCurDir` to be an IO *action*, we want it to be the actual list of files.  To do this, we need to use `<-` in place of `let`:

```
printDirectory :: FilePath -> IO ()
printDirectory dir = do
    filesInCurDir <- getCurrentDirectory >>= getDirectoryContents    -- << CHANGE HERE
    forM filesInCurDir $ \fry -> do
      let fry = "__FAKEFILEPATH__" -- DEBUGGING
      isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fry
      if isDirectory
         then do printDirectory fry -- FIXME
         else putStrLn fry
      putStrLn "Directory search completed"
```

Now, we still have a type mismatch on the `forM` statement, but we're getting closer:

> ```
> Directory.hs:9:5: error:
>       • Couldn't match type ‘[()]’ with ‘()’
>         Expected type: IO ()
>           Actual type: IO [()]
>       • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
>           forM filesInCurDir
> ```

GHC expected `forM` to have type `IO ()` (i.e., an action that does some printing and returns nothing AKA "unit" AKA `()`), but instead `forM` is trying to return a whole *list* of `()`.  This happens when you use `forM` (which builds a list to return) in place of `forM_` (which just runs some IO actions for their side effects, like printing, but doesn't return anything itself).  So, you need to replace `forM` with `forM_`, and you can now safely remove the "DEBUGGING" statement:

```
printDirectory :: FilePath -> IO ()
printDirectory dir = do
    filesInCurDir <- getCurrentDirectory >>= getDirectoryContents
    forM_ filesInCurDir $ \fry -> do      -- << CHANGE HERE
                                          -- << REMOVE DEBUGGING
      isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fry
      if isDirectory
         then do printDirectory fry -- FIXME
         else putStrLn fry
      putStrLn "Directory search completed"
```

It type checks with no errors!

Unfortunately, if you try to run it, it just goes into an endless loop, but that's because the recursion is broken.  The directory contents include the special entries `"."` and `".."` which you will want to skip but even if you fix that, the function doesn't actually ever change the current directory, so if there's at least one subdirectory, it'll just keep checking the current directory over and over.

So, I guess it's still debugging time!

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me understand why I was getting the errors and helping to fix them. I know the recursion was broken but with the errors I couldn't run the code to work on getting the recursion right. Thank you again for your help.